# How to get rid of this popup when hovering over a label in the Chord Diagram (Holoviews - Python)

Tags: python, holoviews, chord-diagram, chord

Exactly like the title says, I've used some code that I collected from multiple places to build up this Chord diagram, but unfortunately one last thing that's kind of going to hinder that 100% perfection is this popup that shows up whenever I hover over the label. The pop up remains there even when the mouse is moving elsewhere...
By the way, I'm using Python and Holoviews for plotting the chord.
I'm pretty sure this is due to a bug or something... however, I'd love to find a way to bypass it...
Example here : [bug example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TFckf.png)

Code :

```
%%opts Chord [height=600 width=600 title="Transactions from 2000 to 2021" ]
#plot 
#edit links = moves[moves['Transactions'] > x] // x refers to the number of transactions minimum for the diagram display
moves = moves[moves['Transactions']>5]
links = moves
chord = hv.Chord(links)
chord
nodesl = []
c = []
for i, row in moves.iterrows():
    c.append(row[0])
    c.append(row[1])

c = pd.DataFrame(c)
c.drop_duplicates(inplace=True)
c.reset_index(inplace=True)
c.drop(columns='index', inplace=True)
c 

nodes = []
for i, row in c.iterrows():
    nodes.append({'name':row[0]})


nodes = pd.DataFrame(nodes)
# nodes

nodes = hv.Dataset(nodes, 'name')
nodes.data.head()



%%opts Chord [height=800 width=800  bgcolor="black"]
%%opts Chord [title="Transactions from 2000 to 2021 (Countries with over 5 moves)\nTip: Please do not hover over the label as it might produce a bug, else refresh the page" ]

chord = hv.Chord((links, nodes)).select(value=(5, None))

#this function allows text to fit perfectly on the screen
def rotate_label(plot, element):
    text_cds = plot.handles['text_1_source']
    length = len(text_cds.data['angle'])
    text_cds.data['angle'] = [0]*length
    xs = text_cds.data['x']
    text = np.array(text_cds.data['text'])
    xs[xs<0] -= np.array([len(t)*0.019 for t in text[xs<0]])

chord.opts(
    opts.Chord(cmap='Category10', 
               edge_color=dim('Target').str(), 
               node_color=dim('name').str(),
               labels='name',
               label_text_color="white",
               hooks=[rotate_label]
               ))
chord
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please provide a text version of your code (see [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/13145954) why it's necessary) to help us help you.

Answer (score 1):

The `???` usually indicates that some field it's trying to display isn't available; not sure why that would be in this case. You can always override the default tools HoloViews uses for Bokeh by setting `default_tools=[]` and then specify whatever tools you do want, without `'hover'`, e.g. `tools=['save', 'pan', 'wheel_zoom', 'box_zoom', 'reset']`.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I tried using this default_tools without the hover, and it looks like it was disabled by default. I tried using it by default, it brings up more information than before (index, data, screen... instead of just "???")...

Comment: Sounds like an improvement? In any case, if you can make a reproducible example and file a github issue or open a discourse.holoviz.org topic, we can probably help figure out whether it's something not set up properly or a bug.

Comment: It does provide more info, but not the label... sort of a double bladed improvement. I'll open a topic immediately on discourse.holoviz.org! Thank you!

Comment: I was just chatting with a Bokeh developer who mentioned he was working on a similar issue to correct a regression in Bokeh 2.4, involving tooltips shown even when there is no tooltip data. So you can try bokeh 2.3 or earlier (and corresponding compatible versions of HoloViews and Panel), which might address it for now until a 2.4.1 Bokeh release is available with a fix.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up! I'm just glad it's being addressed and other people have come across it...